# Running a function which is binded to a widget in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
def printword(event):
    print("hello")

app = Tk()

textpane = tkinter.Text(app)
textpane.bind('<Control-Key-s>',printword)
textpane.pack()

printword()

app.mainloop()
```

When i run the code it gives me typeerror

```
TypeError: printword() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

how would I fix this ?

Comment: The entire point of these bound callbacks is that they will receive an event object from Tkinter, that includes information about the event (in this case, the keypress). You are not really intended to be able to call them directly, because *an event did not actually occur* - so how should the callback process the non-existent event? If you do not actually care about any event details, then you can just pass some dummy value, such as `None`.

Comment: Try changing `def printword(event):` to `def printword(event=None):`. This sets the `event` argument to `None` if it doesn't receive a value, thus preventing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your function doesn't actually use the `event` object in its body, the simplest solution is to make the event parameter optional:

```
def printword(event=None):
    print("hello")
```

This lets you call it without parameters (`printword()`), while also allowing it to accept the argument passed in from tkinter's event handling mechanism.